# Relationships between $A$ and $A'A$ as projections

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be square matrix of order $\geq 2$. Which statement(s) below is (are) true?
>
> 1. If $A'A$ is an orthogonal projector, then $A$ is an orthogonal projector.
> 2. If $A'A$ is a projector, then $A$ is a projector.
> 3. If $A$ is an orthogonal projector, then $A'A$ is an orthogonal projector
> 4. If $A$ is a projector, then $A'A$ is a projector.

It's easy to show that 3 is true: if $A$ is an orthogonal projector, then $(A'A)^2 = A'A \cdot A'A = A'A \cdot AA = A'AA = A'A$, and $(A'A)' = A'A$.

But I don't know how to show that other options are false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by $A'$ you mean the transpose of $A$.

(1) and (2) are false, consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

(4) is false, consider $A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

As for (3), you seem happy with your proof. You could do a simpler proof since an orthogonal projector is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you! How do you come up with all these counterexamples? Did you have some kind of strategy?

Comment: I was looking for counter-examples of the form x y' where x and y are column vectors.

Comment: Could you explain why? What gave you an idea that you should be looking for xy'?

Comment: Well, any non trivial projector of order 2 is of rank 1. And every rank 1 matrix is of the form xy'.

Comment: I see, thank you for explanation!